# Why is my event listener only triggering after the second button click?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class='container'>
    <a class='back-link' href=" {% url 'supplyshop:catalog'  %}"> Back to Catalog</a>
    <h1 class='cart-h1'>Cart </h1>
    <div class='cart'>
        <div class='cart-items'>
            <div class='cartItem' id='cartDiv'>
                <div class='cart' id='cart-item'>
                    <img class='img' src='https://developers.elementor.com/docs/assets/img/elementor-placeholder-image.png' alt='request image'>
                    <div class='cart-info'>
            
                        <p class='name'>Anti-Bacterial Hand Gel (Gallon) </p>

                        <div class='cart-details'>
                            <button  class='detailsBtn'><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-info"></i></button>
                            <p id='detailsText'></p>
                        </div>

                        <p class='qty-text'>Qty</p>
                        
                        
                        <div class='qty-container'>
                    
                        </br>
                        <input type='button' value='+' class='qty qtyplus' id='plus' field='quantity' />
                        <input type='text' name='quantity' value='1' class='qty' id='inputQty' />
                        <input type='button' value='-' class='qty qtyminus' id='minus' field='quantity' /> 
                        
                        <button class='deleteBtn' id='deleteBtn' type='button'>Delete <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i></button> 
                            
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</div>
```

```
const detailsBtn = document.querySelector(".detailsBtn");
const detailsText = document.querySelector("#detailsText");

detailsBtn.onclick = function toggleDetails(event) {

    if (detailsText.style.display == 'none') {
        // show details
        detailsText.style.display = 'block'

        let details = 'Large Jug'
        detailsText.textContent = details

    } else {
        // hide details
        detailsText.style.display = 'none'
    }
}
```

I am trying to set my details button up so that on the first click it shows the details and on the next click it hides the details. However, it only seems to work correctly after the second click. Does anyone know why this behavior is happening and any tips to fix it? I tried to put my code inside a loop and have that run on the first loop? I also tried to check if the button that the event listener is attached to has a class of "detailsBtn" before running the code. Here is the code snippet https://jsfiddle.net/sbf8Lkh1/3/, the details button is the long button in the middle.

Comment: Can you please provide all relevant code? Preferably, use the snippet feature to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem

Comment: `style.display` only contains the inline style of the element, not the styling applied by CSS. This means that the first time you click the button it will not be `"none"`, so your `else` clause runs instead which adds the inline style so that it works on subsequent clicks. This seems like something that would be better solved using classes and CSS instead of inline styling.

Comment: Another alternative is to initialize the `p` tag with `display = none` , so it has a value the first time

Comment: Since you've called your function `toggleDetails` you may want to use the [`toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) method on [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to match.

Answer (score 0):

The properties on an element's `style` object only contains the inline styles, not the styling applied by CSS. I'm making the assumption that your <p> element is hidden initially by CSS. This means that the first time you click the button it will not be `"none"` so your `else` clause runs instead, which adds the inline style so that it works on subsequent clicks.

You can fix this by adding `style="display: none"` to your <p> element so that `style.display` is `"none"` on the first click but it's good practice to avoid inline styles so I suggest you solve this using CSS and class names.

In the following code snippet I create a CSS rule with a class named `hidden` that hides the <p> element and then the click handler simply toggles that class on the <p> element. To have it initially hidden, the class is applied to the element in the HTML.

```js
const detailsBtn = document.querySelector('.detailsBtn');
const detailsText = document.getElementById('detailsText');

detailsBtn.onclick = function toggleDetails(event) {
            let details = 'Large Jug';
            detailsText.textContent = details;
            detailsText.classList.toggle('hidden');
}
```

```css
#detailsText.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart-details">
  <button  class="detailsBtn"><i class="fa-regular fa-circle-info">i</i></button>
  <p id="detailsText" class="hidden"></p>
</div>
```